# CAS authetication Issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, websphere, cas

I am facing same issue like CAS is Unavailable and also I am using WAS 9. We migrated to WAS 7 to WAS 9.
Here is the error log:

```
[5/19/21 12:08:17:280 CDT] 000000c7 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[cas]: org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@763cfd25 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@904f002a expression = authenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials, messageContext), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'realSubmit' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
            at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:386)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:230)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
            at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
            at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
            at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:44)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
            at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:46)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
        Caused by: org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An OgnlException occurred getting the value for expression 'authenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials, messageContext)' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
            at org.springframework.binding.expression.ognl.OgnlExpression.getValue(OgnlExpression.java:92)
            at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
            at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
            at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
            at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
            ... 49 more
        Caused by: ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "submit" failed for object org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction@2aa86b19 [org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA Entity Manager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection]
            at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1265)
            at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
            at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1329)
            at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
            at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
            at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
            at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
            at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
            at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
            at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
            at org.springframework.binding.expression.ognl.OgnlExpression.getValue(OgnlExpression.java:85)
            ... 53 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.createTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit_aroundBody2(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:85)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit_aroundBody3$advice(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:44)
            at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(AuthenticationViaFormAction.java:1)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
            at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:830)
            at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1253)
            ... 63 more
        Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:41)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:57)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:332)
            ... 80 more
        Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
            at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
            at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
            at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
            at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
            at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
            at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:38)
            ... 83 more
        Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL ''
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:47)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
            ... 88 more
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:326)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
            ... 92 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check configuration of your JDBC drivers:

```
        Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL ''
```